# Byobu crashes saying "pipe: Too many open files y"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, byobu

I am using Ubuntu Server 11.10.

I will leave byobu running. But every few hours it will automatically close saying

> "pipe: Too many open files  y".

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [Bug #713879](https://bugs.launchpad.net/byobu/+bug/713879).  What version of [Byobu](http://byobu.co) are you running?  I added some checks in version 4.43 (Ubuntu 11.10 shipped with 4.37).  You can upgrade to the lastest version by running

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:byobu/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install byobu
```

*Full disclosure: I'm the author and maintainer of Byobu.*

Comment: I am using Version: 4.37-0ubuntu1. I will try use the PPA though.

Comment: I just got the same problem. "pipe: Too many open files
Error: Cannot find master process to attach to!". My ulimit -n is 1024, and it still crashes randomly when I set it to 2048.

Comment: Bob, you got the same problem after upgrading?  What version?

Comment: The version is 5.16-0ubuntu1~ppa5

Comment: I did ulimit -n 4096. This time byobu froze and used 100% cpu. I attached it with GDB and I got these 2 backtraces. http://codepad.org/j2wuBV5X

Comment: Okay, thanks, please add comments to the bug and I'll reopen it.

Comment: Sorry Dustin. I found the real problem. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/877894

Comment: Just after a month or so after using the ppa the problem is back again.